# Show Independence of two random variables $X$ and$Y$

Tags: probability

Suppose that $X$ and $Y$ are independent random variables and $g$ is a real-valued function on $R$.

Show that $g(X)$and $Y$ are independent.

Okay, so i dont really know where to begin with this to be honest,

What i do know is that if $X$ and $Y$ are independent random variables then $$E(XY)+EXEY$$ and $$var(X+Y)=varX+varY$$

Would this information help me with my answer? Would i use one of the probability theorems for independence such as $P(A\cap B)=P(A)P(B)$?

EDIT:
Would i be looking to find $$\mathbf{P}(g(X) = x, Y=y) = \mathbf{P}(g(X) = x) \cdot \mathbf{P}(Y=y),$$
to show independence?

If so what how would i go about this? Many thanks

Any help much appreciated, many thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assume that $X$ and $Y$ are independent, that is
$$
P(X\in A,Y\in B)=P(X\in A)P(Y\in B),\quad \text{for all}\; A,B\subseteq\mathbb{R}.\tag{1}
$$
To show that $g(X)$ and $Y$ are independent, we have to show $(1)$ with $X$ replaced by $g(X)$.

Let $A,B\subseteq\mathbb{R}$. Since $g:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$, we have that $g^{-1}(A)=\{x\in \mathbb{R}\mid g(x)\in A\}$ is also a subset of $\mathbb{R}$. Thus
$$
\begin{align}
P(g(X)\in A,Y\in B )&=P(X\in g^{-1}(A),Y\in B)=P(X\in g^{-1}(A))P(Y\in B)\\
&=P(g(X)\in A)P(Y\in B)
\end{align}
$$
and hence $g(X)$ and $Y$ are independent.

Note that in general we can only talk about the probability of $P(X\in A)$ for certain nice subsets $A$. These are called Borel sets, and hence $(1)$ is only required to hold for Borel sets $A$ and $B$. But this is probably out of the scope of your question.

Comment: Thank you so much! This was amazing :)

Answer (score 0):

If the joint density function of $X$ and $Y$ is the product of the individual densities then they are considered independent. Therefore, $f_{X,Y}(x,y)=f_X(x)f_Y(y)$ the $X$ and $Y$ are independent. Let $Z=f(x)$. You have to show that:

$$f_{Z,Y}(z,y) = f_Z(z) f(y)$$

Start from the joint CDF of $Z$ and $Y$ and see if you can work it out.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, Im not familiar with the notation you used though ($f_{X,Y}(x,y)=f_X(x)f_Y(y)$), what does $f_{X,Y}(x,y)$ mean? Sorry if this sounds stupid but i think my course may use different notation! I am in uk if that is relevent.....Thanks

Comment: The notation is used to indicate that the functions are potentially different. For example, $X$ can be a normal pdf and $Y$ can be a uniform pdf. In this case, $f_X$ refers to the normal and $f_Y$ refers to the uniform and $f_{X,Y}$ refers to the joint density function. Since, I am using the same symbol $f$, I need a way to communicate the idea that the pdfs of $X$, $Y$ and their joint all are potentially different functions.

Comment: Oh okay, i kind of understand, so do i have to show that $P(X=x, Y=y)=P(X=x)P(Y=y)$?

Comment: No, those probabilities would be $0$ as you have continuous random variables.  Start from $P(Z \le z, Y \le y) = P(g(X) \le z, Y \le y)$. Then invert $g(X)$ to re-write the last probability, then use independence of $X$ and $Y$ and see if you can progress.

Comment: Ahh im completely confused!! This notation is not used in my lecture notes or model solutions! :/

Comment: Please see my edit, is this more along the right tracks?

Comment: No density needed to answer this question (which does not assume them, by the way).